# Get TextBox Value and show it as MessageBox WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, dev-c++

When I enter a value in the **TextBox** and then I click the button , the **MessageBox** must show the entered value instead of empty MessageBox.
So how to make the entered value showing on the MessageBox after I clicked the button ?

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

HWND TextBox;
char textSaved[20];
    switch(Message) {
        case WM_CREATE:

        TextBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                "",
                                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                10,10,300,20,
                                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                    "Go",
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                    420, 10, 70, 20,
                    hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);

        break;

        case WM_COMMAND:

            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 1:

                int gwtstat =0;
                gwtstat = GetWindowText(TextBox, &textSaved[0], 20);
                ::MessageBox(hwnd, textSaved, textSaved, MB_OK);
                break;
            }

        break;

        case WM_DESTROY: { PostQuitMessage(0);break;}
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc; 
    HWND hwnd; 
    MSG Msg;
    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    //HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 60, 12));//(brush)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,"WindowClass","Caption",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        640,
        480,
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `HWND TextBox;` inside the `WndProc` means its value is reset (to an uninitialized value) every time your window procedure is called. If you want to save the value you need to make the variable `static` or global.

Answer (score 3):

firstly you need to get the textbox text, in your case it has no id, then use this code for create the textbox with id because in your case the HWND TextBox is reset every time your window procedure is called:

```
 CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 10,10,300,20, hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);
```

Now your textbox have a id and we not need of the HWND TextBox, use GetDlgItem for get the TextBox and the GetWindowTextW for get the text of TextBox and store in a wchar_t array:

```
case 1:
    int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 2)) + 1;
    wchar_t text[len];
    GetWindowTextW(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 2), text, len);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, text, L"MsgFromTextBox", MB_OK);
```